# ipad(ios 9.3.5)のsafariでのjavascript関数呼び出しについて

Tags: javascript, php, smarty, ios9

ipad(ios 9.3.5)のsafariでのjavascript関数呼び出しで、参照エラーになります。
サーバ側はphp7+smartyです。
動的にjavascriptを出力したいので、smartyのtplファイル内にjavascriptを記載しています。
javascriptはhaedタグ内でfunction定義を、bodyタグ内部でjs実行しつつ、必要によりfunctionを呼び出しています。

この構成でandroid(chrome)、windows(chrome)、mac osx(safari)、ios(safari)で動作確認をすると、ios(safari)だけ、functionの参照エラーになります。

ざっくりコードを書くと以下ような流れです。

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
①全画面に共通的なfuncton定義
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
②この画面だけのfuncton定義 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
③function呼び出し
</script>
</body>
```

これで①～③の頭でconsole.logでログ出力すると、ios以外では①、②、③の順番にログ出力されるのですが、iosのみは①、③となって、③で②のfunctionを読んでいるので参照エラーになります。
※WEBインスペクタでのデバック実行では②もソースに見えているのに定義実行されません。

分かりにくい文章で申し訳ないのですが、同じような事象に直面した方がおられましたら、ご助言をお願い致します。
ちなみにソースの共通化の都合で、①、②、③は別tplになっていて、画面用tplにインクルードしています。

Comment: 回答には程遠いのですが、とりあえず問題の切り分けのため、①②③の場所に直接`console.log("①");`と記述してみて状況が変化するか確認するというのはどうでしょうか。あと、WEBインスペクタ上で②に定義してある関数を実行できるかどうか確認するとか。

Comment: srcで呼ばれているのではなく直にtplに埋め込まれているのですか？重複定義されているか、インラインコード自体に問題があるかすると、その関数定義全文が見えないと分からないような気がします。サンプルでもコードがない状態だと試験方法を提示するくらいしか出来ないのでは？、あとはtplファイルのそれぞれの文字コードなども確認したほうがいいかもしれません。ちなみにコンソールにエラーや警告などは出ていませんか？

Comment: itmammothさん、Myakuさん、ありがとうございます！

Comment: 結論申しますと、smatyは関係なくて、モバイル版safariのjavascriptにおける関数参照範囲が原因でした。（私なりの調査化結果の解釈です。）
WEBインスペクタでもわかりにくかったので、１つのtplに全てのコードを集約してjavascriptエラーをイベント登録してどんなアラートも逃さないようにしてデバックしました。

すると、iosではready時?(ページ読み込み時最初に)実行されるjavascriptで名前付きfunctionを呼び出していると、同じスクリプトタグ内の、かつ、自分より前にfunction定義がないと参照エラーになってました。

Comment: ですので、上記を考慮して修正すると動きました。
これはモバイル版safariのjavascriptのコードチェックが厳密？で、他のブラウザはアバウトでも上手く解釈してくれていた？という事かと思っています。

Comment: ただ、function定義はheadタグ内で、実行はbodyタグ内でする、という習慣があるので、それが出来ないのは気持ち悪さが残りますが(^_^;